# Getting a template not found error when I use nunjucks base layouts with co-views in koa

Tags: koa, nunjucks

I'm trying to do a basic nunjucks example with koa and I'm getting a not found error when it references a base template

`Error: template not found: layout.html`

index.html

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
<h1>{{ title }}</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

layout.html

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <title>simple example</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Simple example</h1>
{% block body %}{% endblock %}
</body>
```

render.js

```
var views = require('co-views');

module.exports = views(__dirname + '/../views', {
    map: { html: 'nunjucks' }
});
```

server.js

```
const route = require('koa-route');
const parse = require('co-body');
const Koa = require('koa');
const app = new Koa();

var render = require('./lib/render');

app.use(function *(){
   this.body = yield render('index.html', {title:'hello title'});
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log('listening on 3000')
```

The other thing I'm a bit curious about is where is the nunjucks library reference passed in?  Should I be injecting it somehow in render.js?

Comment: This kind of path stuff always seems to require some brute force fiddling, and it's hard to answer this without seeing your directory structure. I wrote an example Koa app that uses Nunjucks that might help you: https://github.com/danneu/koa-skeleton

Comment: if I change the parent path to views/layout.html like in your example it works.. but not sure why it loses the views base path reference in the templates themselves.. using the koa-nunjucks-2 library lets me use the template name without the view/ directory prefix.. not sure where in the process it's losing the relative basepath.

Comment: I realize that it's a failure of the co-views abstraction that tries to generalize an API over all templating libraries and doesn't do a very good job. I recommend switching it out for https://github.com/ohomer/koa-nunjucks-render which solved this issue for me.

Comment: If you want to use nunjucks and koa, i suggest just to make use of https://www.npmjs.com/package/koajs-nunjucks or https://www.npmjs.com/package/koa-nunjucks-2

Comment: Looks like the question was also answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39050788/nunjucks-template-not-found)