# nunjucks: Template not found

Tags: node.js, nunjucks

Trying to render a nunjucks template but getting `Error: template not found: email.html`.

```
server/
  views/
     email/
       email.html
  workers/
      email.worker.js
```

```
//email.worker.js
function createMessage(articles) {
   console.log(__dirname) // /<path>/server/workers

   nunjucks.configure('../views/email/');
   return nunjucks.render('email.html', articles);
}
```

No idea what's wrong here.

Comment: FYI, I also tried configuring the path without the trailing slash.

Comment: I used the `path` module to get the absolute path to the template directory and got it working. Providing relative path did not work.

Comment: Try `nunjucks.configure('views/email/')`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same issue my solution was using path module:

```
const njk = require('nunjucks');

return njk.render(path.resolve(__dirname, '../views/email/' + 'email' + '.html'), articles);
```

Answer (score 8):

Had the same issue, try this if it helps. If you're using express and you have a `views` folder:

From [`nunjucks`](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/getting-started.html) docs

```
var app = express();

nunjucks.configure('views', {
    autoescape: true,
    express: app
});
```

You can use nodejs' `__dirname` to resolve the path for you as

```
nunjucks.configure(__dirname + '/views')...
```

Answer (score 5):

I had same issue. I found this at the [documentation](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/getting-started.html):

> In node, 'views' would be a path relative to the current working directory.

If you run the node server at the root directory, the template path would be `server/views`.

```
 nunjucks.configure('server/views/email/');
 return nunjucks.render('email.html', articles);
```

In my case, the server script is in `public` directory.

[image]

So, when i run the server from the root directory, the nunjucks configuration will look like this:

```
 nunjucks.configure('src/templates');
 return nunjucks.render('index.html', { name : 'Dian' });
```

It works.

But if I run the server from the `public` directory, the tempate will not found.

Answer (score 0):

The nunjucks templates (located under src) were not included in build folder in my case.
Such a configuration in my nest-cli.json file solved my issue:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/nest-cli",
  "collection": "@nestjs/schematics",
  "sourceRoot": "src",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "assets": [
      "**/*.njk"
    ]
  }
}
```